# Understanding and using eth.newFilter

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

**Situation:**

I am using `web3.js` with `geth` for my application to know which clients are depositing money into 1 specific account (instead of making a new wallet for each new client). The way I am attempting to do this is via the **data** value in the **transactionObject:**

```
transcationObject = {
  from: sender,
  to: receiver,
  value: amount,
  data: 2134235141 //uniquely generated value for this user
}
```

**Problem:**

The problem is I need a way for my application to store all the transactionObjects of the accounts that are sending **Ether** to my account. From there it's pretty easy to know who sent how much by looking at the **data** value.

**Potential Solution:**

After searching online, I found the function `eth.setFilter`. **To my understanding,** what this does is filters all the transactions that are being added to the blockchain of the local node, and only saves the ones that pass through the filter.

*source of learning about eth.setFilter:* [How to trace state of transactions in ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/how-to-trace-state-of-transactions-in-ethereum)

**Question:**

Is the previous explanation how `eth.setFilter` actually works? Is it integrated with the process of saving new transaction information into the blockchain?

**AND** could someone provide an example of how it is used? I saw some examples with `curl` online (the link above), but I had no idea what that code actually does. Does it modify how the blockchain operates indefinitely? Or does it need to be re-run? Is there a better way to do it?

**Note:** If some of the questions above are irrelevant to the answer you are providing, it's completely fine. I am mostly trying to find a solution of how to use `eth.newFilter` and understand what it is doing with that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why cannot catch events retrospectively using filter (eth\_newFilter)?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8065/why-cannot-catch-events-retrospectively-using-filter-eth-newfilter)

Comment: you should use bloom filter instead of going through each transaction in each block.

Answer (score 2):

I've used this javascript code to filter transaction to an address, it uses [web3.eth.filter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethfilter)

```
var filter = eth.filter({fromBlock:0, toBlock:'latest', address: "0xAddress"});
filter.get(function (err, transactions) {
  transactions.forEach(function (tx) {
    console.log(tx);
  });
});
```

If instead of `get` to retrieve existing transaction you can use `watch` for new transactions.

A couple of warnings:

- This does not work for 'internal transactions', transactions generated by a contract, for example a multisig wallet or some exchanges. You can use a third party service like etherscan to list 'internal transactions', or use a trace api from geth or parity.
- A chain reorganization can cause that events to be triggered even when transactions will  be dropped from the blockchain. And the opposite an event is not triggered even when the transaction is included in the blockchain. You have to wait some blocks for confirmation, or rescan periodically for chain reorganizations.